# Change the bounds of the integrals.

Tags: integration

We have to change the bounds of the following integrals :

1. $$\int _0 ^4 \Big( \int _{3 x^2} ^{12 x} f(x,y)  \;dy \Big)  dx$$
2. $$ \int _0 ^1 \Big( \int _{2x} ^{3x} f(x,y) \;dy \Big) dx$$
3. $$ \int _{\frac a 2} ^a \Big( \int _0 ^{\sqrt {2 a x -x^2}} f(x,y) \;dy \Big) dx$$

These are my results  :

1. $\sqrt {\frac y 3} <x <\frac y {12} ; \space 0 <y< 48$
2. $\frac y 3< x <\frac y 2; \space 0< y < 3 $
3. $a-\sqrt {a²-y²} < x <a+\sqrt {a²-y²} ; \space 0< y <a² $

Are they correct?

Thank you.

Comment: These can hardly be correct. I'd expect answers in the form $$\int_{\color{red}?}^{\color{red}?}\int_{\color{red}?}^{\color{red}?}f(x,y)\,dx\,dy $$

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen: Because of some formatting issue the original question was not displaying properly. I have edited and reformatted it.

Comment: In #1, the limits for x are reversed; and in #2 and #3, I believe you need two integrals instead of one.